# Troubleshooting Failed SQL login from WMI service

Tags: sql-server

Every 5 minutes I have a couple of failed login attempts from a Biztalk server to the SQL server.

> Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\SERVER01$'. Reason: Token-based
>   server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check
>   for previous errors

I traced the failed logins to back to a service on the Biztalk server. The failed PIDs were pointing to a wmiprvse.exe that was using a LOCAL SERVICE.

I know I could either grant the Biztalk server access to the SQL server or I could change that service to run with a different account BUT I'd like to know what is using the WMI service before doing this.

How can you tell what is using the WMI service?

Comment: Check the application event log for errors on the Biztalk server?

Comment: After more digging in the Ops Manager Log, it turns out it was some Biztalk discovery tool. Still looking for a way to find out how to troubleshoot the WMI service though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tracing WMI activity**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa826686%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**Logging WMI activity**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392285%28v=vs.85%29.aspx